# Understanding the last two Linear Transformations in LeNet-5

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cnn

I need help with understanding the LeNet-5 CNN:

1. *How/Why does FC3 and FC4 have 120 and 84 parameters?*
2. *How are the filters 6 and 16 chosen? (intuition based on the dataset?)*

[image]

Everywhere that I have looked, I haven't found an answer to #1, including LeCunn's original [paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf).

***What am I missing?***

I am tasked with swapping out the 5 x 5 kernels (f = 5), with 3 x 3 kernels (f = 3).  If I understand where those values (especially 84, 120) come from, I think I will be able to do it. I was able to implement LeNet-5 using PyTorch.

If you have any suggestions what values would work best and why, I would be grateful. The dataset is [Cifar-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html).

**Update:**

I modified my code, as @Oxbowerce suggested to make to sure the the image size before unflattening matches the image size in the view before activating the first fully connected network:

In my constructor for the class LeNet:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4 * kernel_size * kernel_size * 16, 120)  # added 4
```

In the feed forward network:

```
x = x.view(-1, 4 * self.kernel_size * self.kernel_size * 16) # added 4
```

Here is my network class:

```
class LeNet(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, activation, kernel_size:int = 5):
    super().__init__()

    self.kernel_size = kernel_size

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=6, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=1)

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4 * kernel_size * kernel_size * 16, 120)  # added 4
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84) 
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    self.activation = activation

def forward(self, x):

    x = self.pool(self.activation(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(self.activation(self.conv2(x)))

    x = x.view(-1, 4 * self.kernel_size * self.kernel_size * 16) # added 4

    x = self.activation(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.activation(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)

    return x
```

I call the train method with this:

```
model.train(activation=nn.Tanh(), learn_rate=0.001, epochs=10, kernel_size=3)
```

Train method:

```
def train(self, activation:Any, learn_rate:float, epochs:int, momentum:float = 0.0, kernel_size:int = 5) -> None:

    self.activation = activation
    self.learn_rate = learn_rate
    self.epochs = epochs
    self.momentum = momentum

    self.model = LeNet(activation=activation, kernel_size=kernel_size)
    self.model.to(device)

    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=self.model.parameters(), lr=learn_rate, momentum=momentum)

    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        loss = 0.0
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        predicted = 0

        for batch_id, (images, labels) in enumerate(self.train_loader):
            images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = self.model(images)
            
            # Calculate accurracy
            predicted = torch.argmax(outputs, 1)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item() # <--- exception
            total += labels.size(0)
            
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        accuracy = 100 * correct / total
        self.train_accuracy.append(accuracy)
        self.train_error.append(error)
        self.train_loss.append(loss.item())

        self.test()

    for i in self.model.parameters():
        self.params.append(i)
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 593, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/unittest/case.py", line 550, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "/home/steve/workspace_psu/cs510nlp/hw2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/steve/workspace_psu/cs510dl/hw2/test_cs510dl_hw2.py", line 390, in test_part2_relu_cel_k3
    model.train(activation=activation, learn_rate=learn_rate, momentum=momentum, epochs=epochs, kernel_size=kernel_size)
  File "/home/steve/workspace_psu/cs510dl/hw2/cs510dl_hw2.py", line 389, in train
    correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
  File "/home/steve/workspace_psu/cs510nlp/hw2/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 27, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
Exception: The size of tensor a (16) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice for the number of neurons in the last two dense layers and the number of filter is somewhat arbitrary and most of the time determined by trying different configurations (using something like a hyperparameter grid search). See also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/345489) on stats stackexchange. If you want to change the size of the 5x5 kernels you will only have to change the number of neurons in the first  fully connected layer, the last two don't have to change for the network to be "valid".

Comment: Thank you @Oxbowerce. I added my code above. Shouldn't I change all kernel sizes to 3, except for the pooling layers?  Sorry, if this is not the place to post code, I'll ask on stack overflow.

Comment: It depends on for which layers you want to change the kernel size, if it just for the convolutional layers you would only have to change the kernel sizes for `self.conv1` and `self.conv2`.

Comment: If I wanted to change just the convolutional layers and not the pooling layers, I would need to change the four lines above and make sure they are using the kernel_size param, right?

Comment: You'd need to change the first two lines to the kernel size you want to use, the number of neurons in your fully connected layer depends on tensor size and not on the kernel size (at least not directly, in this example the kernel size and image size happen to be equal).

Comment: Kernel size and image size need to be equal?  I'm not sure I understand. Image size is 32 x 32 pixels, with 3 channels for color.

Comment: They do not need to be equal, it is just that in this case they are equal (i.e. image size before unflattening is 5x5 and the kernel size for the convolutional layers is also 5x5). That is why using `kernel_size` to calculate the number of neurons in the first fully connected layer works, this won't work if you change the `kernel_size` to 3.

Comment: That is what I am changing kernel to 3.  That is my assignment.  I am changing everywhere except for the pooling kernel.  That is what I should do, right, except I am getting an exception: Exception: "The size of tensor a (16) must match the size of tensor b (4) at non-singleton dimension 0" on the line: "correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()"

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks @Oxbowerce.  You helped me work thru this.

Comment: Yeah, that 4 * kernel_size * kernel_size * 16 works only when the kernel size is 3. It's not apparent to me how I can avoid using if statements before those two lines of code, if kernel_size = 3, add 4.